# NoClassDefFoundError org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook

Tags: java, apache-poi, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

I am running a shell script which calls a java class to get some data from database and create an excel report with that data. I get the error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook when the code hits the below line in my java class:

```
XSSFWorkbook  workbook = new XSSFWorkbook ();
```

This is how I have defined the classpath:

```
CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:<path-to-jars>/poi-2.5.1-final-20040804.jar
CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:<path-to-jars>/poi-ooxml-3.11.jar
```

I verified that the jars have been downloaded(via gradle), so trying to understand what am I missing here. Can someone please help me with this?

Stacktrace:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at com.test.ExcelReportGenerator.writeExcel(ExcelReportGenerator.java:26)
        at com.test.ReportRunner.createReport(ReportRunner.java:109)
        at com.test.ReportRunner.main(ReportRunner.java:93)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 15 more
```

Comment: Why don't you use Gradle to build an executable JAR file? I don't think the shell script is needs to be given your classpath

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per [this Apache POI FAQ entry](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10204), mixing POI jars between different versions *is not supported* and will break in all sorts of ways, such as the one you've found. **Don't do it!**

You need to be using your POI jars all from the same release. I'd suggest [the latest version, available here](http://poi.apache.org/download.html) (currently 3.15)

You should probably also review the [components and their dependencies page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components), to ensure you've got all the required jars for your use of Apache POI. Well, or use a dependency management tool like Maven or Gradle to handle that for you!

Answer (score 4):

I have downloaded the latest Apache POI binaries v3.17 [here](http://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-3.17) and it has all the required jars to create xlsx file and open with out any fuss.

Required jars are shown in below screenshots (refer to selected jars) FYR.

[image: Main Jars]

[image: Supported Jars]

[image: Supported Jars]

Answer (score 3):

For apache poi to work, you need compatible jars.
I used these jars

```
      <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
             <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
             <version>3.9</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
             <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
             <version>3.9</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
             <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
             <version>3.9</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
             <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
             <version>3.9</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
             <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
             <version>1.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
             <artifactId>openxml4j</artifactId>
             <version>1.0-beta</version>
      </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Delete the poi jar from your maven repository and download or build the project again.

Answer (score 0):

poi 2.5.1 had no such package (and consequently a class) included (you can verify by unpacking the jar files as they are essentially zip archives). See the [source](https://github.com/apache/poi/tree/REL_2_5_1/src/java/org/apache/poi).

Update the poi dependency to release 3. This also has the added benefit of matching the ooxml version.