# Getting the follwoing Error "Typed variable declaration : Class: Workbook not found in namespace"

Tags: java, regex, jmeter, beanshell, post-processor

I am receiving the following error,

```
2019-01-24 12:11:27,579 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables; import org.apache.poi.ss.userm . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Class: Workbook not found in namespace.
2019-01-24 12:11:27,579 WARN o.a.j.e.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables; import org.apache.poi.ss.userm . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Class: Workbook not found in namespace
```

I am trying to execute following code

```
    import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;

    log.info("before");
    FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File("File Path"));
    log.info("excelFile");
    Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
    excelFile.close();
    log.info("before3");
    Sheet s = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    //Sheet s = wb.getSheet("Bulk Upload");
    int lines = FileUtils.readLines(new File("File Path")).size(); // get lines count
    //vars.put("lines", String.valueOf(lines)); // store the count into "lines" variable
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<=lines;i++)
    {
    log.info("during");
    Row row = s.getRow(i);
    Cell a1 = row.getCell(0);
    String a1Value = a1.getStringCellValue();
    Cell a2 = row.getCell(1);
    String a2Value = a2.getStringCellValue();
    Cell a3 = row.getCell(2);
    String a3Value = a3.getStringCellValue();
    Cell a4 = row.getCell(3);
    String a4Value = a4.getStringCellValue();
    }
    log.info("after");
```

Please, let me know why I am getting this error and where I should make the correction

Comment: What's the path to the library?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) JAR file has not been set correctly on your classpath. You need to add it to your classpath.

Alternatively, if you're sure that you have, indeed, included the JAR file on your classpath, be sure that you aren't running into a diamond dependency problem and using two different versions simultaneously. According to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40321789/4851565) on a similar (albeit not apparently duplicate) problem, Apache POI doesn't work well with multiple versions on the classpath.