# ClassNotFoundException using maven dependencies in JavaFX

Tags: maven, javafx, dependencies, apache-poi, pom.xml

im working on a script, that should generate excel files for every cost center in my company. Because its my first time using apache poi i started with a regular java application, but now i want to change to JavaFX where i can drop the file with drag and drop.
The regular java application works perfect but now when i want to use JavaFX i get a ClassNotFoundException for a class in the Apache Poi Jar. i use the exact same dependencies like i used in the regular java application i dont even get a real error just this:

```
Model created
Init
DROOOOOP
SETUPPPPPPP
Java Messsge:org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet
```

The first three are all Outprints but the last is the error message. i debugged throught the whole project and it stops in the Throwable class and ther i see this:[Variables from the debuger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lc72S.png)

First i thought its the same issue as here: [NoClassDefFoundError org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320849/noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-poi-ss-usermodel-workbook)

but all my jars have the same version 4.1.2
Here is my pom-File
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0

```
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>RFCHelper</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>module-info.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.mycompany.rfchelper.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for manual attach debugging -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run@debug -->
                        <id>debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=localhost:8000</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE debugging -->
                        <id>ide-debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE profiling -->
                        <id>ide-profile</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg1}</option>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg2}</option>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg3}</option>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg4}</option>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg5}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>                
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>openjfx</id>
            <activation>
                <jdk>[11,)</jdk>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
                    <version>11</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
                    <version>11</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <dependencies>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20230227</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and my jar-files:[Jar-Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EAPx.png)

I also tried adding the shade-plugin as descriped here: [NoClassDefFoundError on Maven dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568275/noclassdeffounderror-on-maven-dependency)

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

this also dosent work so i tried this solution:[Java ClassNotFoundException with maven dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811392/java-classnotfoundexception-with-maven-dependency)
also with no success so i hope that someone here can help me. im pretty a newbee in JavaFX
if you need any further code like the model the controller or the App.java just ask:
THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: You need to find the complete stack trace. If an exception is being thrown and you're not seeing a stack trace, it's almost certainly because somewhere in your code you have a `try-catch` block that suppresses it. Are you running this in an IDE? Or are you trying to run from a jar file?

Comment: i'm runnning it in netbeans. i also thoought this is the issue, but when i add outprints to my catch blocks i never see them in my output.

Comment: Please, [no images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/230513).

Comment: Your [tag:poi] versions don't match, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8202181/230513); also consider a more recent version.

Comment: Your build with the explicit module-info exclusion is strange.  JavaFX is made to execute as a modular library (either via adding a module-info or VM args).  Though shaded jars can sometimes be made to work, it is not supported.  I don't think POI is modular, so probably best to make your app non-modular and either use a JDK that includes the JavaFX modules (e.g. Liberica "Full JDK") or add the JavaFX modules from the JavaFX SDK via VM arguments [documented at openjfx.io: JavaFX and NetBeans, non-modular with Maven](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/). Get the openjfx HelloWorld app working.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But the classic JavaFX-example is working. i dont think i have probles with the JDK.

Comment: and i think my poi-version are the same as in the example